# Importing a library inside a function

Tags: r, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow with Rstudio, and trying to make it as simple and as functionalized as possible. I was wondering if there is a way to call a library inside a function, without having to do this :

```
library(tensorflow)
myFunction(args)
```

Is there a way to embed the first command in the function, so that I don't have to call it each time before using the function ?

I tried something like that :

```
Lamdadou <- function(R) {
library(tensorflow)
sess =tf$Session()
K <- sess$run(R)
print(K) 
}
```

But an error rises when I call it :

```
 Error: Python module tensorflow was not found.
```

Comment: I'm confused, or I don't have enough context. What *doesn't* work if you make `library(tensorflow)` the first line of `myFunction` ? (You may be making some redundant `library()` calls, but these aren't very expensive if the package has already been load.)

Comment: @BenBolker I've tried doing this, but I got an error when calling the function :  Error: Python module tensorflow was not found.

Comment: (1) it would be good to include that information in your question, (2) could we please have  a reproducible example?

Comment: @BenBolker done !

Comment: This seems to be an issue specific to `tensorflow`. Because it requires Python dependencies, I had to run `pip install --upgrade virtualenv`, `pip install tensorflow -U` in terminal, then go back to R. After that it worked fine.

Comment: use `require()` inside a function instead of `library()`

Comment: Thanks all for the answers ! @kevin.arseneau Thanks, this solved the problem ! please add your comment as an answer so as I can accept it /

Comment: @kevin.arseneau `require` on its own is actually pointless, because it simply returns a TRUE/FALSE value. Unless you do something with that return value, if the package fails to load, your function will simply fail as soon as it tries to use something from that package. So you might as well just use `library` and fail straight away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within functions you should use `require` and not `library` to load packages.

So your function should look more like this:

```
Lamdadou <- function(R) {

  if (!require(tensorflow)) {

    stop("tensorflow not installed")

  } else {

    sess <- tf$Session()
    K <- sess$run(R)
    print(K)

  }

}
```

Comment: I'm surprised that this solved the problem, since (as @HongOoi commented), `library()` and `require()` are nearly identical in their function ...